# Net Core 3.1. System.Text.Json. Десериализация. Парсинг даты в формат DateTime

Tags: c#, json, .net-core

Столкнулся с проблемой десериализации даты:

1. Api отдает мне два формата даты(у каждого запроса свой формат):

   **в 1 запросе** - "dateFrom" : "/Date(1569186000000+0300)/",

   **во 2 запросе** - "dateFrom": "01.01.20"
2. Преобразуя данные форматы в строку, проблем нет. Но я бы хотел преобразовать сразу в дату. Пробовал пометить атрибутом, но безуспешно:

   ```
   public class GetInfoResult : BaseResult {
       public Dates[] Dates { get; set; }

       public class Dates {
           [JsonPropertyName("dateFrom")]
           [JsonConverter(typeof(DateTime))]
           public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; }
       }
   }
   ```

Подскажите, как можно правильно преобразовать для 1 и 2 запросов?

Можно ли сделать что-то универсальное, возможно свой тип, наследуемый от DateTime, который будет принимать и преобразовывать нужные мне форматы в дату?

Comment: Атрибут JsonConverter должен принимать класс кастомного конвертера, а не тип данных.

Comment: @vitidev Вы можете уточнить: есть ли стандартные конвертеры для парсинга указанных выше форматов или же нужно писать свой?

Comment: У них плохо с датами. Даже для TimeSpan пришлось свой конвертер писать. Так что писать свой.

Comment: @vitidev спасибо! Напишу свой, а может и просто буду отдавать строкой, кто знает какой формат потом потребуется бизнесу...